# How do I display random nodes within a week?

Tags: nodes

I have added Global:Random in Sort Criteria.

It displays nodes that are too old. How could I set the period to 1 week?

[image]

***The nodes displayed are from last year and year 2013, how to set views to display nodes within a week.***
[image: The nodes display last year and year 2013]

Comment: Add a filter for creation date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add filter for **Content: Post date** and configure the filter criteria as follows:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I have no Content:Post date in filter. Only have Node:Post date. Is it Drupal version? I am using Drupal 6.

Comment: Yes in Drupal 6, it is Node: Post date.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by below steps.

1. Add filter criteria **Content: Post date**.
2. Follow the screenshot for **Content: Post date** field configurations.

[image]